# In CakePHP, where would I put a method that performs a check on the Session User?

Tags: php, cakephp, separation-of-concerns, cakephp-2.4

**Background:** I have a method `levelCheck()` which compares the current user's level to a few parameters, and returns a true or false.  I need to be able to access this method from any controller, and I would also like to put a call to it inside a helper for use on menus, etc.

---

**Question:** Due to Cake's flexibility, I can call almost anything from almost anywhere with Cake.  Where is the correct place to put this?  In a custom Session (extended)?  In the AppController?  A new component dealing with the current user?  In the UserModel or User Controller?

The important piece here is how would I (or others) determine the correct location for such a thing in the future?

Comment: I don't use CakePHP (or even PHP), but can you not use DI/IoC to inject a service into the controller and then invoke a request to that as appropriate? Each controller that needed this service would request it via DI (and the IoC lifetime could be configured appropriately, such as per-request). This is what I do for my ASP.NET code and it (IoC supported by DI) works really well to cross-cut/separate such concerns and nicely encapsulate testable logic.

Comment: Is this "levelCheck" related to *authorization* or *access*?

Comment: Access, but it does have other applications

Comment: It seems that for access/authorization should be handled outside of the specific controllers (so that the basic security can be separated) - with an additional method of usage in the other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this method in AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller 
{

  function levelCheck(){
    # whatever
  }

}
```

This is the correct place of this action. Because AppController is extended in all the controller so this method can called using current controller object that is $this->levelCheck().

Comment: I don't like this. The action is not necessarily an aspect of every controller.

Comment: @user2864740 why I mean do you have any better option or opinion?

Comment: I would use DI/IoC, if at all possible. I'm *not* a fan of subtype inheritance in general, but it seems like it's particularly ill-suited in this place. If this approach is followed for this single method, what happens when there are N methods across M different types of actions? Should the same pattern be followed? That is, this action doesn't necessarily "belong" to the (or all) controller(s), but it seems well suited to belong to a *service* (dependency) that particular controllers/views may use.

Comment: In case of N methods across M different types of actions, i will use plugins but in the above scenario he is trying to check user level which will be used in almost every action so it will be better to put this action in AppController.

Comment: Follow up question: how do I then pair this with a helper?  As I understand, it's discouraged to have a helper call a controller method.. but it's certainly not DRY to write that method twice, and passing data doesn't accomplish what the method itself is capable of.  What would you suggest?

Comment: @xtraorange why do you want to call it from helper? then I can think about the actual scenario?

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, for use on menus and other view constructs.  It can be used to check if a user matches a whole gambit of possible scenarios, which is equally useful in views/elements.  If you need a concrete example, consider the extremely simple idea of testing if a user a moderator, and should have a small element displayed for moderator messages.  The applications would be deeper, but that's easy to quickly grasp

Comment: In that case set some variable from appcontroller and use that variable for your needs

Comment: @Anubhav, a variable alone would not be sufficient, given the depth of possibilities that the method performs.  I need access to the method itself in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

On AppController

```
function beforeFilter() 
 {

      $this->custome_componnetst_name->levelCheck(parameters.....); 
      /*action*/

}
```

Comment: To clarify: the question is not where the method should be executed, but rather where it should be defined.

Comment: define levelCheck() in  custome componnetst.