# In CakePHP, how do I call an AppController method from a helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Follow up question to: [In CakePHP, where would I put a method that performs a check on the Session User?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493623/in-cakephp-where-would-i-put-a-method-that-performs-a-check-on-the-session-user)

---

**Background:** In my previous question, I was informed that the correct place to place a method such as `levelCheck()` which performs a semi-complicated evaluation of a user's level, and is needed in practically all my controllers, is the `AppController`.

Now, this method is also incredibly useful for the way I design menu layouts and other view devices.  For that reason, I would like to create a helper that can make use of that method.

**Problem:** I recognize that it's generally frowned upon to call a controller method from the view... however there is no viable way for me to pass data to replicate the function of this method, nor do I want to replicate the method in two places (violating DRY methodology).

**Question:** How then do I call this method from a helper, or is there a better way to provide use of this method in the view/elements?

Comment: Although a bit early in cake 2.x, but you may consider `trait` with your levelCheck logic. If you have PHP 5.4.x. Just put the trait in `/Lib` and call `App::uses('LevelCheckTrait', 'Lib');` and in controller/helper write `use LevelCheckTrait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to move the method to a component (`CurrentUserComponent`).

From there, it was as simple as calling the component in the head of my helper...

```
App::uses('CurrentUserComponent', 'Controller/Component');
```

And referencing the component's static method:

```
CurrentUserComponent::levelCheck(x,y,z);
```

I don't think this is entirely within the intention of the MVC pattern, but it doesn't pervert it horribly, and allows access to the method from anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Put the method in AppController, also - set a variable that will save the result.

In the `beforeRender` callback, set the result as a viewVar.

some code:

```
// AppController

class AppController extends Controller 
{

  $levelCheckResult = null;

  function levelCheck(){
    $this->levelCheckResult = true/false;
  }


  function beforeRender(){
    $this->set('levelCheckResult', $this->levelCheckResult);
  }
}
```

that's it, now you can access it in the view.

### edit

---

create a public function in the app_controller, and in the `beforeRender()`, send the app_controller itself, to the view.

```
class AppController extends Controller 
{

  function levelCheck(){
    ....
  }


  function beforeRender(){
    $this->set('TheApp', $this);
  }
}
// in the view
$TheApp::levelCheck();
```

However, please consider again the design. this kind of manipulation is strongly suggest that you should change some stuff there.

In short - the view is still backend execution of the program and not the client side, so in definition - it should and can be controlled, from the controller...

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, there is no way to pass data that would sufficiently provide the flexibility I get in the method itself.  I essentially can check a whole host of possible scenarios, to see if a user qualifies or does not.  The exact details aren't really helpful to the scope of the question, but just understand that there is no way for me to pass data sufficient to represent the scope of what I can test with that method... so I need the actual method.

Comment: @xtraorange what you describe (your view should connect to the database) can only suggest that you are doing something wrong. in MVC - the logic that the view is using, is basic and should be - at most - to control a flow or for aggregation.

Comment: The logic is doing nothing more or less than indicating if a user should or should not have access.  I don't think 'how' it ascertains that is really relevant to the discussion.  If it helps, think of it as nothing more than checking if a user is admin or not... but recognize that it needs be a custom function to do so (rather than just straight up reading the session)... that's roughly the purpose of the method, just checking more possibilities than merely admin.  Does that clarify?

Comment: I still don't understand why it should be called in the view. the view is meant only to render, the *already* processed data. the view is executed *after* the controller is done, it's the natural order of mvc execution ## using my way will set a variable (it can be an object with any type of information..) that can be compared to anything. ## note that by adding the `beforeRender` call, will make sure that the variable will be set every time.

Comment: I understand the order of MVC, but not everything falls neatly into the MVC pattern; that's simply not how it works out and I'm sure you know that.  Things such as menus, where I'm creating links based on the method's results for various checks... or whatever other elements I might add or take away based on checks using that method.  And once again (and I'm very confident, so please just trust me and consider other solutions), a variable will not possibly be able to contain the many possible dimensions that method can check.

Comment: It's rather like if you suggested putting sqrt() into a variable.  It doesn't make any sense... the results are totally dependent on the input.

Comment: I Can't accept what you say, since I never encountered such issue. **I have no dough that it should and can be done in the controller** however, as to a solution for you question, ignoring the design..
sending the app-controller itself (edited answer)

Comment: Okay, let's approach this a different way, since clearly we're not connecting.  Here's the scenario: you have several menus, each of which has various links on it, some to be displayed to certain types of people, some to be displayed to others (etc)...  You also have some other element odds and ends, some up to your web developer to add for the look of the site, which are either shown or not shown based on user criteria. There is a method, which given criteria, determines if the current user meets or does not meet those requirements.  How do you (according to your view of MVC) create them?

Comment: *The criteria are a combination of a comparator, a level, and an override array.  The method chugs all this (and some other random bits) to come up with a true/false.

Comment: Another way to approach this: you were comfortable with setting an admin variable with true or false, which I assume means you're comfortable with doing `if($admin === true)` before a menu item.  All I'm doing is more complex, but essentially the same, check, such as: `if($userlevel > registered && $userlevel != moderator && $userlevel !=junioradmin...` etc.  It would be foolish to make the web developer write something like that out, and make sure they got all the right logic, when I already have a method that does the same logic, and keeps it simple.  And it wouldn't be DRY to rewrite it.

Comment: As i wrote:you are not limited to a Boolean variable. you can send an object. with level, rank and even favorite color.
and, in the view - you will have ALL this data available to compare.
##
If you want to avoid DRY, you should create a comparison function in a helper, and use it against the result object. because, worst than DRY is to execute a complete code over and over again..
## Moreover,if you will call the function in every junction, instead of using its result that already stored in the object - it will only add unneeded CPU cycles..
I will try later to add a more complex example.

Comment: I'm not sure what your suggesting.  I already have access to the data, that's not the problem.  The problem is the method itself, which does the comparison.  I simply want access to that, which is where this question started.  I have the data, but the comparisons I'm doing are less than simple, and require their own method.  There's no value in trying to pass the results of the method, which you've suggested numerous times, because of the complex number of possible inputs to the method (51,200 possible combinations by my calculations).  All I need is the method.

Comment: In the last example, that's exactly what i showed you. access to the method, which is in the controller..
AND - i also told you that you should move this method to a helper, since you are not supposed to access a controller's method from a view

Comment: My original question mentions that I want to create a helper around this, not access it from the view.  As I mentioned, passing the entire app seems heavy handed... is there no better way?

Comment: The only way i can think of, is keeping the AppController instance in a global variable, in this way you are only passing a pointer.